# Obtain Access token to Docusign using Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, docusignapi

I am tying to obtain Access Token using Google Apps Script.

Ref: https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/jwt/jwt-get-token/

Using Postman, I can get the ACCESS TOKEN by posting a request using this URL: `https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/token`
and this two fields in the body:

- `grant_type : urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer`
- `assertion : MY_JSON_WEB_TOKEN`

How do I replicate tis in Apps script? 
After endless hours of trial and error I still get this error: `{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"unsupported_grant_type"}`

The script:

```
function obtainAccessToken(){
  const JWT = MY_JSON_WEB_TOKEN;

  const URL = 'https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/token';

  const PARAMS = {
    "muteHttpExceptions": true,
    "method": "POST",
    "contentType": "application/json",
    "payload": {
      "body":{
        "grant_type": "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer",
        "assertion": JWT
      }
    } 
  };

  return UrlFetchApp.fetch(URL, PARAMS);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the correct function:

```
function obtainAccessToken(){
  const JWT = MY_JSON_WEB_TOKEN;

  const URL = 'https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/token';

  const PARAMS = {
    "method": "POST",
    "headers":{
      "Accept": "application/json",
      "contentType": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    },
    "payload": {
      "grant_type": "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer",
      "assertion": JWT
    } 
  };

  return UrlFetchApp.fetch(URL, PARAMS);
}
```

Comment: This works? Or this is part of your **question?**

Comment: This is not part of the question. This is the working function. It is the answer to the question.

Comment: Great! Thank you for posting. Please mark it as the answer to your question (check the "accepted" checkbox by the answer).